# Audio Playlist In WinUi 3 Desktop Application

Tags: c#, xaml, desktop-application, winui-3

I have an array of 4 songs and i have to play that 4 song in a loop on a image in `winUi 3` desktop application. I have played one song on a image and below is my code

```
 mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

 mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("www.example.com"));

 mediaPlayer.IsLoopingEnabled = true;

 mediaPlayer.Play();
```

But now i have to play 4 song as a playlist.
Can anyone help me out

Comment: What do you mean by "play [...] in a loop on a image in winui3 desktop"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [MediaPlaybackList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlaybackList?view=winrt-22621) and [MediaPlaybackListItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplaybackitem?view=winrt-22621):

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
MediaPlaybackList mPlaybackList = new();
mPlaybackList.Items.Add(new MediaPlaybackItem(MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("www.example.com")));
mediaPlayer.Source = mPlaybackList;
mediaPlayer.Play();
```